# Multi layer perceptron weights not changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am fairly new to Machine Learning and started off with [Machine Learning an algorithmic perspective](https://seat.massey.ac.nz/personal/s.r.marsland/MLBook.html). I am trying to make a logistic classifier that identifies malign programs from benign ones by tweaking the code given on book website. However the weights associated with the hidden layer and output layer are not changing even after 100000 epochs.

I have tried running the algorithm with the complete dataset as well as a partial version of it, still no luck.

Here is my MLP class

```
import numpy as np
class mlp:

def __init__(self, inputs, targets, nhidden, beta=1, momentum=0.9, outtype='logistic'):
    """ Constructor """
    # Set up network size
    self.nin = np.shape(inputs)[1]
    self.nout = np.shape(targets)[1]
    self.ndata = np.shape(inputs)[0]
    self.nhidden = nhidden

    self.beta = beta
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.outtype = outtype

    # Initialise network
    self.weights1 = (np.zeros((self.nin + 1, self.nhidden), dtype=float) - 0.5) * 2 / np.sqrt(self.nin)
    self.weights2 = (np.zeros((self.nhidden + 1, self.nout), dtype=float) - 0.5) * 2 / np.sqrt(self.nhidden)

def earlystopping(self, inputs, targets, valid, validtargets, eta, niterations=100):

    valid = np.concatenate((valid, -np.ones((np.shape(valid)[0], 1))), axis=1)

    old_val_error1 = 100002
    old_val_error2 = 100001
    new_val_error = 100000

    count = 0
    while (((old_val_error1 - new_val_error) > 0.001) or ((old_val_error2 - old_val_error1) > 0.001)):
        count += 1
        print
        count
        self.mlptrain(inputs, targets, eta, niterations)
        old_val_error2 = old_val_error1
        old_val_error1 = new_val_error
        validout = self.mlpfwd(valid)
        new_val_error = 0.5 * np.sum((validtargets - validout) ** 2)

    print("Stopped", new_val_error, old_val_error1, old_val_error2)
    return new_val_error

def mlptrain(self, inputs, targets, eta, niterations):
    """ Train the thing """
    # Add the inputs that match the bias node
    inputs = np.concatenate((inputs, -np.ones((self.ndata, 1))), axis=1)
    change = range(self.ndata)



    print(self.weights2)
    updatew1 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights1)))
    updatew2 = np.zeros((np.shape(self.weights2)))

    for n in range(niterations):

        self.outputs = self.mlpfwd(inputs)

        #error = 0.5 * np.sum((self.outputs - targets) ** 2)
        if (np.mod(n, 100) == 0):
             print ("Iteration: ", n, " Weight2: ", self.weights2)


            # Different types of output neurons
        if self.outtype == 'linear':
            deltao = (self.outputs - targets) / self.ndata
        elif self.outtype == 'logistic':
            deltao = self.beta * (self.outputs - targets) * self.outputs * (1.0 - self.outputs)
        elif self.outtype == 'softmax':
            deltao = (self.outputs - targets) * (self.outputs * (-self.outputs) + self.outputs) / self.ndata
        else:
            print("error")

        deltah = self.hidden * self.beta * (1.0 - self.hidden) * (np.dot(deltao, np.transpose(self.weights2)))

        updatew1 = eta * (np.dot(np.transpose(inputs), deltah[:, :-1])) + self.momentum * updatew1
        updatew2 = eta * (np.dot(np.transpose(self.hidden), deltao)) + self.momentum * updatew2
        self.weights1 -= updatew1
        self.weights2 -= updatew2

        # Randomise order of inputs (not necessary for matrix-based calculation)
        # np.random.shuffle(change)
        # inputs = inputs[change,:]
        # targets = targets[change,:]


    print(self.weights2)

def mlpfwd(self, inputs):
    """ Run the network forward """

    self.hidden = np.dot(inputs, self.weights1);
    self.hidden = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-self.beta * self.hidden))
    self.hidden = np.concatenate((self.hidden, -np.ones((np.shape(inputs)[0], 1))), axis=1)

    outputs = np.dot(self.hidden, self.weights2);

    # Different types of output neurons
    if self.outtype == 'linear':
        return outputs
    elif self.outtype == 'logistic':
        return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-self.beta * outputs))
    elif self.outtype == 'softmax':
        normalisers = np.sum(np.exp(outputs), axis=1) * np.ones((1, np.shape(outputs)[0]))
        return np.transpose(np.transpose(np.exp(outputs)) / normalisers)
    else:
        print("error")

def confmat(self, inputs, targets):
    """Confusion matrix"""

    # Add the inputs that match the bias node
    inputs = np.concatenate((inputs, -np.ones((np.shape(inputs)[0], 1))), axis=1)
    outputs = self.mlpfwd(inputs)


    nclasses = np.shape(targets)[1]

    if nclasses == 1:
        nclasses = 2
        outputs = np.where(outputs > 0.5, 1, 0)
    else:
        # 1-of-N encoding
        outputs = np.argmax(outputs, 1)
        targets = np.argmax(targets, 1)

    cm = np.zeros((nclasses, nclasses))
    for i in range(nclasses):
        for j in range(nclasses):
            cm[i, j] = np.sum(np.where(outputs == j, 1, 0) * np.where(targets == i, 1, 0))

    print(outputs)
    print(targets)

    print("Confusion matrix is:")
    print(cm)
    print("Percentage Correct: ", np.trace(cm) / np.sum(cm) * 100)
```

Here is my calling code that supplies data

```
import mlp
import numpy as np

apk_train_data = np.array([
    [4, 1, 6, 29, 0, 3711, 1423906, 0],
    [20, 1, 5, 24, 0, 4082, 501440, 0],
    [3, 0, 1, 6, 0, 5961, 2426358, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 27, 0, 6074, 28762, 0],
    [12, 1, 3, 17, 0, 4066, 505, 0],
    [1, 0, 2, 5, 0, 1284, 38504, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 10, 0, 2421, 5827165, 0],
    [5, 0, 17, 97, 0, 25095, 7429, 0],
    [1, 1, 3, 22, 6, 4539, 9100705, 0],
    [2, 0, 4, 15, 0, 2054, 264563, 0],
    [3, 1, 6, 19, 0, 3562, 978171, 0],
    [8, 0, 5, 12, 3, 1741, 1351990, 0],
    [9, 0, 5, 12, 2, 1660, 2022743, 0],
    [9, 0, 5, 12, 2, 1664, 2022743, 0],
    [10, 4, 11, 70, 8, 43944, 51488321, 1],
    [6, 0, 3, 18, 0, 8511, 19984102, 1],
    [11, 2, 6, 44, 0, 61398, 32139, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1008, 23872, 1],
    [7, 1, 1, 16, 3, 46792, 94818, 1],
    [3, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8263, 208820, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2749, 3926, 1],
    [10, 0, 1, 9, 0, 5220, 2275848, 1],
    [1, 1, 3, 34, 6, 50030, 814322, 1],
    [2, 2, 4, 48, 7, 86406, 12895, 1],
    [0, 1, 5, 45, 2, 63060, 803121, 1],
    [1, 0, 2, 11, 7, 7602, 1557, 1],
    [3, 0, 1, 15, 3, 20813, 218352, 1]
])
apk_test_data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 4317, 118082, 0],
    [8, 0, 5, 12, 3, 1742, 1351990, 0],
    [8, 0, 5, 12, 3, 1744, 1351990, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 11, 2, 17630, 326164, 1],
    [10, 2, 6, 45, 7, 22668, 30257520, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 8, 0, 9317, 33000349, 1],
    [3, 0, 1, 15, 3, 20813, 218352, 1]
])

p = mlp.mlp(apk_train_data[:, 0:7], apk_train_data[:, 7:], 9)
p.mlptrain(apk_train_data[:, 0:7], apk_train_data[:, 7:], 0.25, 100000)
p.confmat(apk_test_data[:, 0:7], apk_test_data[:, 7:])
```

Each vector has 7 dimensions and last entry is the target

Here is the full text file containing the dataset
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q_aGNgHxTBh_mmVAzVXKBa27NTJKeKV8

Please tell me what am I doing wrong. In case there is some easy to use library to do the same please suggest the same.

Comment: That is a big read..but as far as I can see, you initialize all your weights to 0. Could you try to initialize weights randomly instead?

Comment: @Uvar sir you are a genius!! Initializing weights to random values is changing the weights over training. But can you explain the logic behind this? I mean theoretically initializing weights to 0 should also work. And also I am still not able to get good accuracy. Please suggest some way to improve it.

Comment: A very simple way to improve it, is by decreasing `eta`. Another is by standardizing the data before feeding it to the network. :)

Comment: @JamesHowlett if you initialise all your weights to zero then gradient descent step updates will be zero from the get go, meaning you never update the weights at any step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, initializing the network weights randomly should make the network train.

```
    # Initialise network
    self.weights1 = (np.random.rand(self.nin+1,self.nhidden)-0.5)*2/np.sqrt(self.nin)
    self.weights2 = (np.random.rand(self.nhidden+1,self.nout)-0.5)*2/np.sqrt(self.nhidden)
```

Then, my observation from your data is that the properties are not at all comparable. This will mean that your network gradient updates will be dominated by a single feature. To remedy that, one option is to standardize your data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
for i in range(apk_train_data.shape[1]-1):
    scaler = StandardScaler().fit(apk_train_data[:,i].copy())
    apk_train_data[:,i] = scaler.transform(apk_train_data[:,i].copy())
    apk_test_data[:,i] = scaler.transform(apk_test_data[:,i].copy())
```

And last but not least, having `eta` be 0.25 is way too big. I'll illustrate by using the opposite extreme:

```
p.mlptrain(apk_train_data[:, 0:7], apk_train_data[:, 7:], 0.0001, 100000)
p.confmat(apk_test_data[:, 0:7], apk_test_data[:, 7:])
# >> Percentage Correct:  71.4285714286
p.confmat(apk_train_data[:,0:7], apk_train_data[:,7:])
# >> Percentage Correct: 88.8888888889
```